# PHP8: vertical line with a type?

Tags: php

I found this line of code to be problematic on a server running PHP7.4:

```
public function expiresAfter(int|\DateInterval|null $time);
```

I get a ParseError, with PHP expecting a variable. Couldn't find the symbol's usage as it is here in [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What do the vertical bars mean here? Also is there a way to rewrite this so it works with PHP7.4?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775489/is-it-possible-to-type-hint-more-than-one-type is what it is, for earlier versions you may need to just remove the type hint altogether.

Comment: Thank you. Removed the hinting, it was present only in that particular line, fixed the whole solution. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are union types (new in PHP8):

Union types are a collection of two or more types which indicate that either one of those can be used.

Example:

```
public function foo(Foo|Bar $input): int|float;
```

They work like an **or** condition on Object/Type you can use as an input parameter. In this example you can either use *Foo* or *Bar* as an input parameter, but nothing else.

If you want to get your code working on PHP7.4 just remove the types like so:

```
public function foo($input);
```

Source: https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8#union-types-rfc