# Whats wrong with this problem in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have this problem while deploying my laravel project online o dont know why it shows

03-Sep-2022 23:43:55 Asia/Manila] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/eksperto/ekspertofiles/vendor/nunomaduro/termwind/src/Functions.php on line 17

I even tried to delete that line but nothing happens im new to this can someone help me thanks

Comment: Im currently using php 8.1 but the php version on my server is 7.4

Comment: Thats your problem probably. In termwid composer json you have `"require": { "php": "^8.0",`

Comment: I don't know which *version* of Termwind you're using, but line 17 of Functions.php for [the current version](https://github.com/nunomaduro/termwind/blob/master/src/Functions.php#L17) uses a union type declaration for the function arguments. This syntax was introduced in PHP 8.0. Note that PHP 7.4 is end-of-life [in two months](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), so you should probably update your server to use PHP 8.0 at minimum (which reaches end-of-support in two months) or preferably PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Type unions were introduced with PHP 8 -
see [Is it possible to type hint more than one type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826132/5841606)

The line uses that apparently.

```
function renderUsing(OutputInterface|null $renderer): void
```